# Why can't CMAKE find my SFML libraries in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

I am trying to run `SFML` on `CLion` with `CMAKE`, and I keep getting the following error:

> Error:Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY
>   SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY
>   SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY)

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build (Debug or Release)" FORCE)
endif()

project(Polymorphism)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Polymorphism ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${main.cpp} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

*Impossible to tell, since we don't know your environment.*

However, this should usually help:

Add a new CMake variable `SFML_ROOT` and let it point to the directory where SFML is installed.

Just add the variable to your CMakeCache.txt or pass it the first time you run CMake, e.g.:

```
cmake -DSFML_ROOT=/code/SFML path/to/source
```

Also you've got a problem further down below:

```
target_link_libraries(${main.cpp} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

The first parameter is supposed to be the target, in your case `Polymorphism`. Also you should add `SFML_DEPENDENCIES` just in case someone tries to link SFML statically. In the end this line should look like this:

```
target_link_libraries(Polymorphism ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```